# How to 'If Author' Comments Check

Tags: comments, admin, author

I would like to add extra markup to a comment made by the site admin/post author. Is there a check for this and how would I add it to my code below?

Basically, if the comment is from the post author I would like to add HTML next to their name (Author or Admin).

Thanks

```
            <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata ">         
                <?php printf(__('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">said on</span>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>
                <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) ?>">
                <?php
                    printf( __('%1$s at %2$s'), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()) ?></a><?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'),'  ','' );
                ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [`comment_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_class) function to add classes to each comment, comments by the post's author can be styled via the `bypostauthor` class.

You can alternately match the comment ID against the post ID:

```
global $post;
if( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) {
    // is author comment
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a undeclared variable warning. `Notice: Undefined variable: post in /Users/huw/Sites/mamp/MyProjects/canvas/wp-content/themes/canvas/functions.php on line 252

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/huw/Sites/mamp/MyProjects/canvas/wp-content/themes/canvas/functions.php on line 252`

Comment: you have to globalize `$post` if you're using it within a function, see edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I have very simple solution to this.
Just add this code to your theme’s comments.php file

```php
<?php
if (1 == $comment->user_id)
  echo 'author';
?>
```